# Facing Issues with CSS Animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am trying to create a text that would fade into view after a few seconds but I am facing problems. The fade into view is working fine but the text disappears almost immediately after it is shown. Secondly I need this animation to work in a delayed manner but when I set the delay it doesn't seem to make any difference. The delay was working fine earlier.

Why does the animation disappear shortly after it is shown? What should I do to get it displayed correctly? Why is the delay not working now? Please help me. The solution must be simple but I am probably not thinking along the right line.

The below is my code.

HTML:

```
<div id="container" class="container">
    <span class="fadeText">Sample Text</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    margin: 5% auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.fadeText{
    color: #5B83AD;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 125%;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #5B83AD;
    padding: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 5s;
    animation-delay: 5s;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 5s ease-in;
    -moz-animation: fadeIn 5s ease-in;
    animation: fadeIn 5s ease-in;
}

/* Animations */
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn{
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn{
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes fadeIn{
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
/* End of Animations */
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hg4Xy/

Note: I have extracted only the relevant portion of the code and posted here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `animation-fill-mode` to `forwards`. Currently your animation is executing fine but it is going to its original state (which is `opacity: 0`) after the last key-frame is executed. Setting fill-mode to `forwards` would make the text retain the opacity set by the last key-frame (which is `opacity: 1`). **Alternatively,** you can remove the `opacity: 0` property from `.fadeText`.

```
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* always use standard un-prefixed version as last */
```

Set the `animation-delay` after the `animation` property in the CSS. Currently it is being set before the `animation` property and since the `animation` short-hand property doesn't specify any delay it is getting over-written. **Alternatively,** modify the short-hand property as shown below.

```
-webkit-animation: fadeIn 5s ease-in;
-moz-animation: fadeIn 5s ease-in;
animation: fadeIn 5s ease-in;
/* set delay after animation */
-webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
-moz-animation-delay: 5s;
animation-delay: 5s;

/* addresses both items. 4th parameter is for delay and 5th is for fill mode */
-webkit-animation: fadeIn 5s ease-in 5s forwards;
-moz-animation: fadeIn 5s ease-in 5s forwards;
animation: fadeIn 5s ease-in 5s forwards;
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/EgEVb/)

Comment: wow thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. The delay was initally written in shorthand and I changed it for some reason, silly me :(