# How to stop animation at the last frame

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I am trying to rotate a cube in a three direction. I need to stop the animation at the 3rd Box but its comes to original position. From the 3rd box there is an animation back to the 1st box which I don't want.The animation should stop at 3rd Box. Give some solution.

```css
#spinner div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 120px;
  font-size: 100px;
}
#spinner .face1 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(60px);
}
#spinner .face2 {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(60px);
}
#spinner .face3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(60px);
}
@-webkit-keyframes spincube {
  from, to {} 16% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg);
  }
  33% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(90deg);
  }
}
#spinner {
  -webkit-animation-name: spincube;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 8s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 60px 60px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="stage" style="width: 1200px; height: 300px;">
  <div id="spinner">
    <div class="face1">1</div>
    <div class="face2">2</div>
    <div class="face3">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facing Issues with CSS Animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394420/facing-issues-with-css-animation)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode

Comment: Interestingly your code does have `animation-fill-mode` set to `forwards`. What browser are you trying this on?

Comment: Thanks harry I am using Chrome.

Comment: exactly thanks a lot  harry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though you had set the `animation-fill-mode` to `forwards` (the `-webkit` prefix should not be a problem as you were trying on Chrome), the animation did not stop at the 3rd box because your `to` setting (last keyframe) was taking it back to its original state (which shows box 1). To fix this, you can make the last `keyframe` also hold the same position as at 33% (which is show box 3).

```css
 #spinner div {
   position: absolute;
   width: 120px;
   height: 120px;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
   text-align: center;
   line-height: 120px;
   font-size: 100px;
 }
 #spinner .face1 {
   -webkit-transform: translateZ(60px);
 }
 #spinner .face2 {
   -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(60px);
 }
 #spinner .face3 {
   -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(60px);
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes spincube {
   from {} 
   16% {
     -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg);
   }
   33% {
     -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(90deg);
   }
   to {
     -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(90deg);
   }
 }
 #spinner {
   -webkit-animation-name: spincube;
   -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
   -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
   -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 8s;
   -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
   -webkit-transform-origin: 60px 60px 0;
 }
```

```html
<div id="stage" style="width: 1200px; height: 300px;">
  <div id="spinner">
    <div class="face1">1</div>
    <div class="face2">2</div>
    <div class="face3">3</di>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Or, you could also change your `keyframe` settings like below. Note that, I have reduced the duration by a third because we are changing the keyframes by a factor of 3.

```
 @-webkit-keyframes spincube {
     from {
     }
     48% { /* factor of 3 since we are changing 33% to 100% or to */
         -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg);
     }
     to { /* make the last keyframe show the box 3 */
         -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(90deg);
     }
 }
 #spinner {
     -webkit-animation-name: spincube;
     -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
     -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
     -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
     -webkit-animation-duration: 2.7s; /* reduce total duration by a 3rd */
     -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
     -webkit-transform-origin: 60px 60px 0;
 }
```